# ASP.NET MVC web app - Generate .RDP file with encrypted credentials?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, encryption, rdp

I have a simple ASP.NET MVC application that produces .RDP files for users to login to test machines in our integration testing environment. The application is hosted on a Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise with IIS v7. The users are on Windows 7 Enterprise SP1. A user simply chooses a machine and then chooses an account, and the .RDP file is generated to either be saved or opened. But, they currently are provided with the account password on screen and have to type it into the RDP dialog box.

I would like to remove the manual effort of entering the password into the initial RDP credentials box by encrypting the password in the .RDP files. I'm able to successfully encrypt the password and launch directly into a remote session when I run the application in debug mode on my machine. However, from the research I've done, it appears that the password encryption/decryption process will only work when the .RDP file is accessed by the same user from the same machine where the password was encrypted...

Does anyone have any ideas how I can host the application on the web server, but still allow users to generate encrypted .RDP files that they can use on their client machines?

I'd greatly appreciate any feedback you may provide! Thank you kindly in advance!

Comment: Well it sounds like it'll be [quite a challenge](http://superuser.com/a/456800) for good reasons though....

Comment: Thank you for the comment @EdSF. Strong security is indeed a good thing... However, I did find your linked thread earlier and I understand that it is a challenge. I'm hoping someone might have a suggestion regarding how to actually go about it, if it is indeed possible?